# Questions about Camera Remote API beta and DSC-QX100

Tags: camera, sony

I have few questions and hope that someone from Sony will answer them.

We want to control the behaviour of a DSC-QX100 camera from the outside to get a continuous video (and sometimes during this process good quality photos).
Our tasks are: to get a real-time video stream of resolution not less than 720p, 25fps, any encoding (raw, motion jpeg, mpeg4, h264), and to get in real-time photos taken after pressing the button on the camera.
So the questions are:

1. Is it possible to change API beta LiveView resolution (by default it's 640x480)?
2. Is it possible to detect using API beta that moment when the photo is taken, and if such event occurs, to get it? As I understand API beta don't provide such functionality, but PlayMemories have it.
3. Is there any available interfaces on the DSC-QX100 that can provide video stream (maybe we can access them after disassembling the camera)?
4. We found that camera hasn't got digital zoom. If no, how can we control it?
5. Is it possible to access the control of focus settings? API beta request returns an "forbidden" error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Camera Remote API beta (API) does not provide API to change resolution of LiveView.
2. Please check actTakePicture, getEvent, awaitTakePicture to see if they will be useful for you.
3. All the functionality exposed, is documented.
4. Check actZoom API to see if it will work for your application.
5. From the previous announcement, you already know, many APIs like shutter speed, ISO will be expanded for QX cameras. Please wait for actual API expansion announcement for exact details (Official timing - Spring 2014).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! When the information will be?